# Please merge sql-clr and clr

Tags: support

Both tags refer to the same thing. Also, sqlclr should be added as an alias.

Apparently my messsage body is too short, so I shall write a few sentences upon the virtues os Aaron Bertrand and Paul Kiwi.

Aaron and Paul are awesome. They answer my questions.

Comment: There's just two questions with [clr], just retag them. Unless you think [clr] should be the master tag. In which case you could have said that in your question.

Comment: Paul Kiwi? You mean Paul White, right? (Since you called him awesome, I guess that *must* be him.)

Comment: @AndriyM Undoubtedly. There is only one Paul, awesome and Kiwi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mat suggested, please go ahead and re-tag if necessary.

If you think there should be a synonym [clr](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clr)-->[sqlclr](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sqlclr) you need someone with domain knowledge and [2.5k rep](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to propose a synonym, (or get them to ask a mod).

Either way feel free to pop into [The Heap](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap-consultancy-) to ask - you may even bump into someone awesome ;)